# R: Predicting future panel data

Tags: r, panel-data, prediction, plm

I have an unbalanced panel covering the years 2000-2017 for multiple countries (some missings as unbalanced suggests), for which I ran a fixed effects model with `plm`:

```
fit<-plm(y~x1+I(x_1^2)+x2+x3, data=final[final$year<=2017,],index = c("country", "year"), effect = "individual", model="within")
```

I have data for `x1`,`x2` and `x3` for 2018-2030 and want to compute the estimator for y for these years based on that data (including fixed effects). 
I found the `prediction` package which apparently allows to do exactly that (the normal `predict`function apparently only computes the y's for the observations used in the regression).

```
prediction(fit, data=final[final$year>2017,], at=NULL, calculate_se=FALSE)
```

I unfortunately now get an error message:

```
Error in crossprod(beta, t(X)) : non-conformable arguments
```

Can somebody explain to me what that means and what I have to do to generate predictions for my data? 
Is there maybe another, better method for that?

Answer (score 6):

Prediction with panel data is kind of tricky.  Your model seems to be
$$
  Y_{it} = X_{it}'\beta + c_i + u_{it}
$$
where $c_i$ is an individual fixed effect.  You have estimated the $\beta$'s with plm.  But to get a prediction, you need to plug in some values for $X$ and for the fixed effect.  Even if you just want to get predictions for the individuals in your sample, the fixed effect is not consistently estimated unless $T \rightarrow \infty$ which is not really the case here.  Also, if you want to get predictions outside of your sample, you will need to somehow come up with a value for the fixed effect which, I think, ultimately is just going to be something you make up.

`crossprod(x,y)` just computes $x'y$.  The error you're getting is because the dimensions of the matrices are not compatible (perhaps due to the unbalanced panel).  I would run `debug("prediction")` and then step through the code until you find out what is in `beta` and `X`.